Getting the SLD_BODY parameter to work with ArcGIS Mapserver WMS 1.3.0
I am trying to dynamically change the external WMS style's file using the SLD_BODY parameter to visualize an external WMS service with a different color.
My basic XML SLD script is below.
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version='1.0.0' xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/sld' xmlns:ogc='http://www.opengis.net/ogc' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd'>
 <NamedLayer>
  <Name>style_sld_body</Name>
  <UserStyle>
    <FeatureTypeStyle>
     <Rule>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
       <Fill>
        <CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</CssParameter>
        <CssParameter name="Fill-opacity">0.699999988079071</CssParameter>    
       </Fill>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
    </FeatureTypeStyle>
  </UserStyle>
 </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>

'''
The URL version of this is below.

%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D'1.0'%20encoding%3D'ISO-8859-1'%3F%3E%0A%3CStyledLayerDescriptor%20version%3D'1.0.0'%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fsld'%20xmlns%3Aogc%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fogc'%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink'%20xmlns%3Axsi%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema-instance'%20xsi%3AschemaLocation%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fsld%20StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd'%3E%0A%20%3CNamedLayer%3E%0A%20%20%3CName%3Estyle_sld_body%3C%2FName%3E%0A%20%20%3CUserStyle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CFeatureTypeStyle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3CRule%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPolygonSymbolizer%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CFill%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CCssParameter%20name%3D%22fill%22%3E%23FF0000%3C%2FCssParameter%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CCssParameter%20name%3D%22Fill-opacity%22%3E0.699999988079071%3C%2FCssParameter%3E%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FFill%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FPolygonSymbolizer%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRule%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FFeatureTypeStyle%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2FUserStyle%3E%0A%20%3C%2FNamedLayer%3E%0A%3C%2FStyledLayerDescriptor%3E

I can get to the default style using GetMap with the following URL.

https://mapprod3.environment.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/services/Planning/SEPP_Housing_2021/MapServer/WmsServer?&request=GetMap&layers=1&version=1.3.0&width=4096&height=4096&crs=EPSG:4326&format=image%2Fpng&bbox=-33.962923656903406,151.1256483206996,-33.93178292067633,151.1628872722676&STYLES=default

The above URL gives me the following result.

To change the color of the polygons to red with the URL version of the XML SLD script, I have tried the below on the browser.
https://mapprod3.environment.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/services/Planning/SEPP_Housing_2021/MapServer/WmsServer?&request=GetMap&layers=1&version=1.3.0&width=4096&height=4096&crs=EPSG:4326&format=image%2Fpng&bbox=-33.962923656903406,151.1256483206996,-33.93178292067633,151.1628872722676&STYLES=style_sld_body&EXCEPTIONS=XML&SLD_BODY=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D'1.0'%20encoding%3D'ISO-8859-1'%3F%3E%0A%3CStyledLayerDescriptor%20version%3D'1.0.0'%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fsld'%20xmlns%3Aogc%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fogc'%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink'%20xmlns%3Axsi%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema-instance'%20xsi%3AschemaLocation%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fsld%20StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd'%3E%0A%20%3CNamedLayer%3E%0A%20%20%3CName%3Estyle_sld_body%3C%2FName%3E%0A%20%20%3CUserStyle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CFeatureTypeStyle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3CRule%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPolygonSymbolizer%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CFill%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CCssParameter%20name%3D%22fill%22%3E%23FF0000%3C%2FCssParameter%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CCssParameter%20name%3D%22Fill-opacity%22%3E0.699999988079071%3C%2FCssParameter%3E%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FFill%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FPolygonSymbolizer%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRule%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FFeatureTypeStyle%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2FUserStyle%3E%0A%20%3C%2FNamedLayer%3E%0A%3C%2FStyledLayerDescriptor%3E
But this is giving me an error. It shows, that the style 'style_sld_body' is not assigned for layer '1'.
What am I missing here? Does ArcGIS Server's WMS version 1.3.0 support sld_body parameter at all?

The <Name> of a <NamedLayer> needs to correspond to the layer you are assigning a custom style to. styles also needs to be set to a real style configured in the WMS, but in your case you can probably set it to nothing.
Since you have layers=1 you can take 1 as the layer name, which gives you this url:
https://mapprod3.environment.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/services/Planning/SEPP_Housing_2021/MapServer/WmsServer?&request=GetMap&layers=1&version=1.3.0&width=4096&height=4096&crs=EPSG:4326&format=image%2Fpng&bbox=-33.962923656903406,151.1256483206996,-33.93178292067633,151.1628872722676&STYLES=&EXCEPTIONS=XML&SLD_BODY=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%271.0%27%20encoding%3D%27ISO-8859-1%27%3F%3E%0A%3CStyledLayerDescriptor%20version%3D%271.0.0%27%20xmlns%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fsld%27%20xmlns%3Aogc%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fogc%27%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%27%20xmlns%3Axsi%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema-instance%27%20xsi%3AschemaLocation%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fsld%20StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd%27%3E%0A%20%3CNamedLayer%3E%0A%20%20%3CName%3E1%3C%2FName%3E%0A%20%20%3CUserStyle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CFeatureTypeStyle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3CRule%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPolygonSymbolizer%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CFill%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CCssParameter%20name%3D%22fill%22%3E%23FF0000%3C%2FCssParameter%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CCssParameter%20name%3D%22Fill-opacity%22%3E0.699999988079071%3C%2FCssParameter%3E%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FFill%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FPolygonSymbolizer%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRule%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FFeatureTypeStyle%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2FUserStyle%3E%0A%20%3C%2FNamedLayer%3E%0A%3C%2FStyledLayerDescriptor%3E


Final SLD:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version='1.0.0' xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/sld' xmlns:ogc='http://www.opengis.net/ogc' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd'>
 <NamedLayer>
  <Name>1</Name>
  <UserStyle>
    <FeatureTypeStyle>
     <Rule>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
       <Fill>
        <CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</CssParameter>
        <CssParameter name="Fill-opacity">0.699999988079071</CssParameter>    
       </Fill>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
    </FeatureTypeStyle>
  </UserStyle>
 </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>

